# Calling a function from another GUI class Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, pyqt

I have a created a GUI in Python that consists of a stacked widget containing 3 seperate widgets, loginBackend, editorBackend, mapBackend. They are all seperate classes also named loginBackend, editorBackend, mapBackend. Each one is called from a class and main window widget called mainBackend. The idea is that the user will login (using loginBackend widget) and will then be able to access the rest of the widgets. The problem is that each of the other widgets need the login information in order to connect to the database. For some reason I cannot get the information to return properly when I am calling it from the editorBackend class. What I am trying to do is something like this

This is the editorBackend

```
from loginBackend import loginBackend

class editorBackend(QWidget, editordesign.Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)  
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.submitPushButton.clicked.connect(self.Insert)

    def Insert(self):
        login = loginBackend()
        url = login.creds()   
        print('url:  ' + url)
```

This is the loginBackend

```
class loginBackend(QWidget, logindesign.Ui_Login):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)  

    def creds(self):
        username = self.userLineEdit.text()
        password = self.passLineEdit.text()
        host = self.selHostLabel.text()
        port = self.selPortLabel.text()
        sid = self.selSIDLabel.text()
        cred = username + '/' + password + '@' + host + ':' + port + '/' + sid
        print('creds: '+ cred)
        return cred
```

Then this is the the main window that calls both of these and puts them into a stacked widget.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QMainWindow
import sys
from loginBackend import loginBackend
from mapBackend import mapBackend
from editorBackend import editorBackend
from editTNSnamesBackend import editTNSnamesBackend
import mainwindow

class mainBackend(QMainWindow, mainwindow.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)  
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.url = None
        self.popList()
        self.login = loginBackend()
        self.mapping = mapBackend()
        self.edit = editorBackend()
        self.editTNS = editTNSnamesBackend()
        self.popWidgets()
        self.listWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.change)
        self.actionTNS_Names.triggered.connect(self.editTNSnames)


    def editTNSnames(self):
        self.editTNS.show()

    def change(self):
        index = self.listWidget.currentRow()
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(index)
        self.url = self.login.creds()
        print('url change.  ' + self.url)

    def popList(self):
        widgets = ['Login', 'Edit Database', 'Edit Mapping']
        self.listWidget.addItems(widgets)

    def popWidgets(self):
        self.stackedWidget.insertWidget(0,self.login)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.login)
        self.stackedWidget.insertWidget(1,self.edit)        
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.edit)
        self.stackedWidget.insertWidget(2,self.mapping)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.mapping)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.listWidget.setCurrentRow(0)

def main():
    app = 0
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = mainBackend()
    main_window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The print statement in the loginBackend and in the main window prints what I need but I cannot get it to print anything in editorBackend. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this or maybe a work around?

The designer files (abbreviated):

logindesign classes:

```
class Ui_Login(object):
    def setupUi(self, Login):
        Login.setObjectName("Login")

        ...
        ...
        ...

 def retranslateUi(self, Login):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
```

editordesign classes:

```
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")

        ...
        ...
        ...

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
```

mainwindow classes:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")

        ...
        ...
        ...

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
```

Comment: Please share the .ui or classes generated through it.

Comment: @eyllanesc the classes generated through what?

Comment: Qt Designer with pyuic.

Comment: I do not want a schema, but the complete code or at least it is reproducible.

Comment: You must provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @eyllanesc it is way too many lines to post here, also I figured out a work around. Thanks anyways

Comment: You could publish it in github and share the link. :P

Comment: Or at least show what you need to run it. :P

Comment: @eyllanesc I will keep that in mind for the future. I just posted a solution if you want to check it out.

Comment: Great, you solved it. I would call it setUrl instead of getUrl.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved my problem by creating a function in the class where I need the information. I could then just pass it as an argument from the main window (where I knew I could get the values). Shown below.

Create a function in the editorBackend

```
from loginBackend import loginBackend

class editorBackend(QWidget, editordesign.Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)  
        self.initUI()
        self.url = None

    def initUI(self):
        self.submitPushButton.clicked.connect(self.Insert)


     #### NEW FUNCTION ####
     def getUrl(self, url):
        self.url = url
        print('getUrl '+url) 
     ######################

    def Insert(self): 
        print('url:  ' + self.url)
```

send the login info from main window to the editorBackend

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QMainWindow
import sys
from loginBackend import loginBackend
from mapBackend import mapBackend
from editorBackend import editorBackend
from editTNSnamesBackend import editTNSnamesBackend
import mainwindow

class mainBackend(QMainWindow, mainwindow.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)  
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.url = None
        self.popList()
        self.login = loginBackend()
        self.mapping = mapBackend()
        self.edit = editorBackend()
        self.editTNS = editTNSnamesBackend()
        self.popWidgets()
        self.listWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.change)
        self.actionTNS_Names.triggered.connect(self.editTNSnames)


    def editTNSnames(self):
        self.editTNS.show()

    def change(self):
        index = self.listWidget.currentRow()
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(index)
        self.url = self.login.creds()
        print('url change.  ' + self.url)

        ### PASS THE INFORMATION TO editorBackend ###
        self.edit.getUrl(self.url)
        #############################################


    def popList(self):
        widgets = ['Login', 'Edit Database', 'Edit Mapping']
        self.listWidget.addItems(widgets)

    def popWidgets(self):
        self.stackedWidget.insertWidget(0,self.login)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.login)
        self.stackedWidget.insertWidget(1,self.edit)        
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.edit)
        self.stackedWidget.insertWidget(2,self.mapping)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.mapping)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.listWidget.setCurrentRow(0)

def main():
    app = 0
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = mainBackend()
    main_window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```